# How to reassign types to vite iso-imports

Tags: typescript, vite, svelte, sveltekit

Im using a library thats telling me in the documentation to use vite iso-import for their sveltekit integration. After following their instructions, I lose access to the library types.

I try to regain types via typescript declaration file, but I couldn't make it work. Library keeps on falling to fallback.

```
declare global {
    namespace App {
    }

    declare module '@amcharts/amcharts5?client' {
        import * as am5 from '@amcharts/amcharts5';

        export = am5;
    }

    // fallback
    declare module '*?client';
    declare module '*?server';
}

export {};
```

[Imports falling back to fallback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11WUR.png)